# the easiest way to upload updated data to the server

Tags: c#, windows

I work on Windows app and every week I want to upload the new data (rows) to the server 
and i want to upload the new db from asp.net web page and i'm using sqlserver2005 for our co branches or from my local server.

What is the best way to do so upload complete db mdf and delete the old one !

Do I update only the new rows and how can I make sure of the old

I want the fastest and easiest solution is to do that programmatically

how to receive mdf file in asp.net If this method easier ?

Seasons greetings
Dani :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From SQL Server, you can perform a backup of the new database, restore the new database to the server, and delete the old database. You can do that manually or in a scheduled job.

Perhaps a more common approach to synchronizing databases is using "replication". While this can become quite complicated, you can probably use the basic functionality. About.com has a short description of it [here](http://databases.about.com/cs/sqlserver/a/aa041303a.htm).

Comment: Glad to help. I hope it solves your problem. Once you set it up, there's very little else you have to do. Just let it run on auto-pilot.